# Architecture guidebook for Java web application?

Tags: java, architecture, java-ee-5

I'm looking for some good books/internet material that discusses on how to make decision on architecture for a Java web application, discuss on various considerations etc.

I found this "J2EE Architecture Book" on TSS :

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/books/DVTPress/J2EEArchitectsHandbook/index.tss

The book is not only dated, but has poor reviews at TSS: 
http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=28152

Anyone have a recommendation keeping in mind modern frameworks such as Spring, Hibernate & EJB 3 etc? Let me know if you need more specifics.

Comment: I read the reviews. You are right, they are terrible!! I'm glad I wasn't the author ;-)

Comment: Avoid this book at any cost, it's indeed an horrible one.

Answer (score 3):

Could [this one](http://press.adam-bien.com/) help you ? I'm haven't seen it yet but I think I'll order it...

Answer (score 3):

Everyone should have [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html) in his bookshelf. This book is not about frameworks as stated in its title (it is about architecture patterns) but, still, it's a, no *the* bible that everyone should read at least once.

Now, regarding the mentioned technologies or frameworks, I'd suggest:

- [**EJB 3 in Action**](http://www.manning.com/panda/) by Reza Rahman. Reza is very active on TSS, he is also a member of the Java EE 6 and EJB 3.1 expert groups. This guy just knows what he's talking about. Globally a very good book (covers the Spring integration too).
- If you want a book about Hibernate 3.x, get [**Java Persistence with Hibernate**](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/), which can be considered as the second edition of [**Hibernate in Action**](http://www.manning.com/bauer/) (excellent book).
- If you are still looking for Spring 2.5 literature, **Pro Spring 2.5** or **Spring Recipe** (have a look at [this comparison](http://java.dzone.com/articles/comparison-books-spring-recipe)). But I'd consider [**Pro Spring 3**](http://www.springer.com/computer/programming/book/978-1-4302-1845-6) because this is where to look at now (I haven't read this one though).

Honestly, with the rollout of Java EE 6, Spring 3, I'm not sure you'll find an all-in-one book covering all that very recent stuff (give the authors a few months). If you do, please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I also have an eye on the book "Spring in Practice", scheduled for release in May this year:

http://www.manning.com/wheeler/

Comment: @Pascal Since you mentioned that * Java Persistence with Hibernate* can be considered a second edition of *Hibernate in Action*, does that mean that *Hibernate in Action* is a **pre-requisite** for reading *Java Persistence with Hibernate*? Do the contents of the books overlap or one is complementary to the other?

Answer (score 1):

You might find [Expert One-on-One J2EE Design and Development](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0764543857.html) by Rod Johnson. It's a bit dated now but the framework he designs in the book formed the basis for the Spring Framework. It might be worth a look.

Comment: I have read the book, but I'm looking for something that takes into account newer frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few good options:

1. Spring in action / Craig Walls, Manning, 2008
2. Struts 2 in action / Donald Brown, Manning, 2008
3. Building Spring 2 Enterprise applications / Interface 21 ; with Bram Smeets, Apress, 2007
4. Beginning JSP, JSF and Tomcat web development / Giulio Zambon, Apress 2007
5. Java persistence with Hibernate / Christian Bauer and Gavin King. Manning, 2007
6. SCEA Sun certified enterprise architect for Java EE  / Paul R. Allen, McGraw Hill, 2007
7. Practical JBoss Seam Projects / Jim Farley, Apress, 2007

cheers -- Rick